# how to download pics to a specific folder location on windows?

Tags: python, selenium

I have this script which download all images from a given web url address:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib


class ChromefoxTest:

    def __init__(self,url):
        self.url=url
        self.uri = []

    def chromeTest(self):
       # file_name = "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\images"
        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        self.r=self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
       # output=open(file_name,'w')

        for i, v in enumerate(self.r):
            src = v.get_attribute("src")
            self.uri.append(src)
            pos = len(src) - src[::-1].index('/')
            print src[pos:]
            self.g=urllib.urlretrieve(src, src[pos:])
          #  output.write(src)
       # output.close()


if __name__=='__main__':
    FT=ChromefoxTest("http://imgur.com/")
    FT.chromeTest()
```

my question is: how do i make this script to save all the pics to a specific folder location on my windows machine?

Comment: What issue are you facing as of now?

Comment: Can you post the errors you are getting ? Also, are you running this script with python 2 ?

Comment: running it with python 2.7, I am not getting errors I download all the images but it is under my project folder I want it to be saved in other folder.

Comment: You should please up-vote answers that are helpful to you. If any of them was especially useful then please mark it 'accepted'.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the path where you want to save the file. This is explained in [the documentation for `urllib.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve):

The method is: `urllib.urlretrieve(url[, filename[, reporthook[, data]]])`.
And the documentation says:

> The second argument, if present, specifies the file location to copy to (if absent, the location will be a tempfile with a generated name).

So...

```
urllib.urlretrieve(src, 'location/on/my/system/foo.png')
```

Will save the image to the specified folder.

Also, consider reviewing the [documentation for `os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html). Those functions will help you manipulate file names and paths.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the **requests** library you can slurp up really big image files (or small ones) efficiently and arrange to store them in a place of your choice in an obvious way.

Use this code and you'll get a nice picture of a beagle dog!

- `image_url` is the link to the remote image.
- `file_path` is where you want to store the image locally. It can include just a file name or a full path, at your option.
- `chunk_size` is the size of the piece of the file to be downloaded with each slurp from the remote site.
- `length` is the actual size of the piece that is written locally. Since I did this interactively I put this in mainly so that I wouldn't have to look at a long vertical stream of 1024s on my screen.

..

```
>>> import requests
>>> image_url = 'http://maxpixel.freegreatpicture.com/static/photo/1x/Eyes-Dog-Portrait-Animal-Familiar-Domestic-Beagle-2507963.jpg'
>>> file_path = r'c:\scratch\beagle.jpg'
>>> r = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
>>> with open(file_path, 'wb') as beagle:
...     for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
...         length = beagle.write(chunk)
```